# Special variable name in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables

is there any way to set variable name MATLAB like this: `dif`(i is in loop)

```
d1f
d2f
d3f
.
.
dnf
```

I've tried `dnum2str(i)f`, but it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: Please do not do this. Dynamic variable names are only going to leave you in a world of hurt. Use a more appropriate data structure such as a cell array or struct with dynamic field names

Comment: Sure! `d_f(1), d_f(2), d_f(3), ... d_f(n)`.

Comment: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html but use a cell instead `df = {}; for i = 1:10   
   df{i} = zeros(1,i);
 end;
df  `